# How to fix log4j vulnerability - Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, log4j

as it is known, log4j vulnerability has emerged. How can we close this gap in our own projects? Do we have a chance to push a version on gradle?

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to help

```
constraints{
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core"){
            version{
                strictly("[2.15,3[")
                prefer("2.15.0")
            }
            because("CVE-2021-44228 : Log4j is vulnerable to remote code execution")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution we used in our spring-boot project where we manage dependencies using the `enforcedPlatform` method:

```
dependencies {
  api(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")) {
    exclude(group: "org.apache.logging.log4j")
  }
  api(platform("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.15.0")) {
    because "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228"
  }
}
```

This is designed to be in-place until such time as we're in a position to upgrade to a version of Spring Boot that pulls in the fixed version itself.

Answer (score 0):

### WARNING:

As of 2021-12-16 The other answers in this thread are out of date. DO NOT USE THE OTHER ANSWERS DIRECTLY.

- log4j v2.15.0 is no longer considered a valid remediation for this vulnerability. See [Apache's Log4J security bulletin](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) for more information

  - <kbd>cntl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for `2.15`

    - [screen shot](https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/)

---

### UPDATE: 2021-12-18...

Remember to always check for the latest information from the resources listed below

**[CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)**... 2.16.0 and 2.12.2 are no longer valid remediations! The current fixing versions are 2.17.0 (Java 8) and 2.12.3 (Java 7). All other Java versions have to take the stop gap approach (removing/deleting JndiLookup.class file from the log4j-core JAR.
I have updated my message below accordingly.

---

- More resources

  - https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/

    - This one has TONS of useful info including detectors, even more resource links, very easy to understand remediation steps, and more
  - https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/apache-log4j-vulnerability-guidance
  - https://github.com/cisagov/log4j-affected-db
  - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html

---

**Remediation:**
**[CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) ... [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) ... [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)**
While most people that need to know probably already know enough to do what they need to do, I thought I would still put this just in case...

- Follow the guidance in those resources... it may change, but

#### As of 2021-12-18

It's basically

- Remove log4j-core JAR files if possible

  - From both running machines for immediate fix AND
  - in your source code / source code management files to prevent future builds / releases / deployments from overwriting the change
- If that is not possible (due to a dependency), upgrade them

  - If you are running Java8, then you can upgrade to log4j 2.17.0+
  - If you are running an earlier version of Java, then you can upgrade to log4j 2.12.3
  - If you are running an older version of Java, then you need to upgrade to the newest version of Java, and then use the newest version of Log4J
  - Again, these changes have to happen both on running machine and in code
- If neither of those are possible for some reason... then there is the NON-remediation stop gap of removing the JndiLookup.class file from the log4j-core JARs.

  - There is a one-liner for the stop gap option on Linux using the `zip` command that comes packaged with most Linux distros by default.

    - `zip -q -d "$LOG4J_JAR_PATH" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`
  - At time of writing, most of the guides online for the stop gap option on Windows say to do the following (again... assuming you can't do one of the remove JAR or upgrade options above):

    - Install something like 7-zip
    - Locate all of your log4j-core JAR files and for each one do the following...
    - Rename the JAR to change the extension to `.zip`
    - Use 7-zip to unzip the JAR (which now has a `.zip` extension)
    - Locate and remove the JndiLookup.class file from the unzipped folder

      - The path is `\\path\\to\\unzippedFolder\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\core\\lookup\\JndiLookup.class`
    - Delete the old JAR file (which now has an extension of .zip)
    - Use 7-zip to RE-zip the folder
    - Rename the new .zip folder to change the extension to `.jar`
  - There are also some options to use Power Shell

    - [Reddit thread: log4j_0day_being_exploited](https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/)
    - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for "PowerShell"

This is fine if you only have 1 or 2 JAR files to deal with and you don't mind installing 7-zip or you have PowerShell available to do it. However, if you have lots of JAR files, or if you don't want to install 7-zip and don't have access to Power Shell, I created an open-source VBS script that will do it for you without needing to install any additional software. https://github.com/CrazyKidJack/Windowslog4jClassRemover

Read the README and the Release Notes https://github.com/CrazyKidJack/Windowslog4jClassRemover/releases/latest

Comment: It's important to note that only the log4j-core JAR is vulnerable. So you may be able to omit that from your project and still use other log4j libraries (like log4j-api)